# ggplot for objects stored in an 3D array

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, plot, line

I have written a following code that is working and plotting what I want, but if I wanted to use ggplot for plotting, how could I have done it?

```r
myseq<-seq(from = 1, to = 99, by = 5)
mtx <- array(rnorm(880,0,1) ,c(4,11,length(myseq)))

plot(myseq,mtx[1,1,],type = "l", col=1) 
lines(myseq,mtx[1,2,],type = "l",col=2)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,3,],type = "l",col=3)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,4,],type = "l",col=4)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,5,],type = "l",col=5)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,6,],type = "l",col=6)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,7,],type = "l",col=7)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,8,],type = "l",col=8)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,9,],type = "l",col=9)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,10,],type = "l",col=10)
lines(myseq,mtx[1,11,],type = "l",col=11)
```

After running this say I get a plot like below, Now how to do this thing using ggplot2?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8xuj.jpg)

Comment: Is `threshold` 19?

Comment: When I run this code (replacing `19` for `threshold`), I don't get that plot, I get errors about vector lengths. When I change `myseq` to be length 19 (inferring that it should pair up with one of the dims of the array), then I get a plot that looks nothing like that. Perhaps I'm being dogmatic, but ... if you're going to say you get a plot from code, perhaps you could use the code that you give us?

Comment: Good edit. Note that because you're filling an array with 836 random numbers into dimensions of `4*11*20` (880), you're recycling 44 of your random numbers. This doesn't change how to plot it, but if this closely mimics your real process, then your data is being corrupted/biased.

Comment: I am sorry. I have changed my question subject and the errors provided are gone now.

Comment: 4*11*19 because the length of myseq is 19.

Comment: `length(seq(from = 1, to = 99, by = 5))` yields 20 on my system. Is it different for you?

Comment: again sorry the rnorm should be 880. you are right about 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` prefers data frames, and for something like this, frames in a long format.

Here's a basic way to do it.

First, reproducible random data.

```r
set.seed(42)
myseq<-seq(from = 1, to = 99, by = 5)
mtx <- array(rnorm(880,0,1) ,c(4,11,length(myseq)))
mtx[1,1:4,1:4]
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]          [,4]
# [1,]  1.3709584 -1.3682810  0.9333463  6.288407e-05
# [2,]  0.4042683 -0.4314462  0.6503486 -1.173196e-01
# [3,]  2.0184237  1.5757275 -1.1317387 -8.610730e-02
# [4,] -1.3888607  0.6792888  1.2009654 -4.138688e-01
```

From here, we can basically convert this 3D array into a four column `data.frame`, where three of the columns indicate the axes, and the fourth is the actual value.

```r
melted_mtx <- reshape2::melt(mtx[1,,,drop=FALSE])
str(melted_mtx, vec.len=15)
# 'data.frame': 220 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ Var1 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#  $ Var2 : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 1 2 3 4 5 ...
#  $ Var3 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 ...
#  $ value: num  1.371 0.404 2.018 -1.389 -0.284 -0.307 1.895 0.46 1.035 -0.784 0.206 -1.368 -0.431 1.576 0.679 -0.367 -0.727 0.921 0.624 ...
```

Since you want to plot `myseq` on the x-axis, we can do a replacement with that. It's in the third variable here, `Var3`. I'll verify that it is the correct length and then do the replacement:

```r
lapply(melted_mtx[-4], table)
# $Var1
#   1 
# 220 
# $Var2
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
# 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
# $Var3
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
# 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 

melted_mtx$Var3 <- myseq[melted_mtx$Var3]
lapply(melted_mtx[-4], table)
# $Var1
#   1 
# 220 
# $Var2
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 
# 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
# $Var3
#  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41 46 51 56 61 66 71 76 81 86 91 96 
# 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

We can use that and feed it to `ggplot2` rather directly.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melted_mtx, aes(Var3, value, group = Var2, color = factor(Var2))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot2 of plane 1]

The base graphics plot of that (your code) renders:

[image: base graphics]

which, margins and colors aside, is effectively the same plot. There is plenty of beautification that can be done, including legend labels, axes, etc.

Above, I only `melt`ed the first plane of the array. If you did the whole array, then it'd look like this:

```r
melted_mtx <- reshape2::melt(mtx)
melted_mtx$Var3 <- myseq[melted_mtx$Var3]
ggplot(melted_mtx, aes(Var3, value, group = interaction(Var1, Var2),
                       color = interaction(Var1, Var2))) +
  geom_line()
```

[image: ggplot2 with all planes]

This is a bit complex, clearly, but with the use of `interaction`, you can group by multiple variables. Grouping is required here, since without it `ggplot2` will try to connect all of the points in a single line, generally not useful. Usually one can get away with using *just* `color=` to suggest the groups, but I often include both `group=` and `color=` in case I later change how colors/linetypes/shapes/... are defined, and groups are accidentally changed.

Comment: can't I plot myseq in the X axis? I do not understand the reshape package much.

Comment: here I understand that the length of myseq is plotted in the x axis.

Comment: That should be a simple "replace" operation, since the index on that dimension of the array is also (by the definition of the array) an index on `myseq`. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much. This has been immensely helpful. 

Now I have to find a way to run this whole thing in a repetitive function. I did not know that ggplot stores all the objects as a global character. Have been trying melted_mtx$Var3,melted_mtx$value inside the aes, let's see.